# How to change the data row 1 equal to row 2 if the row 1 is null?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to change data of `PAYMENTDATE` equal to the data of `CREATIONDATE` whenever the data of `PAYMENTDATE` is `NULL`? For example:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| PAYMENTDATE | CREATIONDATE |
+-------------+--------------+
| 2018-03-21  | 2018-03-01   | 
| NULL        | 2018-04-05   |
| NULL        | 2018-07-06   |
| 2018-09-12  | 2018-08-23   |
| 2018-12-13  | 2018-11-21   |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Here is the my query:

```
SELECT
  details.PAYMENTDATE,
  account.CREATIONDATE
FROM
  account
    INNER JOIN
  details ON account.DETAILSKEY = details.PRIMARYKEY
```

I've tried using

```
IF(details.PAYMENTDATE IS NULL,
    details.PAYMENTDATE = account.CREATIONDATE,
    details.PAYMENTDATE = details.PAYMENTDATE) AS NULLDATA,
```

But it does not work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the value inside `IF` statement.

```
IF(details.PAYMENTDATE IS NULL, account.CREATIONDATE, details.PAYMENTDATE) AS NULLDATA
```

You can also use `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(details.PAYMENTDATE, account.CREATIONDATE) AS NULLDATA
```

Comment: thanks you for your time to help me. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    COALESECE(d.PAYMENTDATE, a.CREATIONDATE) AS PAYMENTDATE
    a.CREATIONDATE
FROM account a
INNER JOIN details d
    ON a.DETAILSKEY = d.PRIMARYKEY
```

The `COALESCE` function works by replacing the first argument with the second argument in the event that the first argument be `NULL`, so in

```
COALESCE(NULL, 3)
```

would return 3, but `COALESCE(3, 5)` would return 3.

Comment: thanks you for your time to help me. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in the if because you assign the value of null in the first return value of your if

```
details.PAYMENTDATE = account.CREATIONDATE
```

Your code should be this way

```
   SELECT
      details.PAYMENTDATE,
      IF(f.paymentdate IS NULL,
                f.CREATIONDATE,
                f.CREATIONDATE) AS NULLDATA,
      account.CREATIONDATE
    FROM
      account
        INNER JOIN
      details ON account.DETAILSKEY = details.PRIMARYKEY
```

Just returning the desired values not assign the others.

I hope my explanation was good (no native speaker)

Comment: The issue is already answered but thank you for taking your time explaining what my code is suppose to look like. Thank you very much sir. Much appreciated.